# Hive date based partitions

Tags: date, hive, partition

I have data in the following form on HDFS:-

```
/basedir/yyyymmdd/fixedname/files
```

Where the yyyymmdd is the date folder and files are the list of files added in the directory. I need a table in hive to pick up data from yyyymmdd/fixedname directory. This should also work when i added a new date. e.g. i add something on 5th March 2013 so all files added on that day would go to 20130305/fixedname folder. On 6th March 2013, all files would go to 20130306/fixedname folder.

How do i alter a hive table to pickup data from the changing date but fixed folder within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a partitioned table? Let's say that you already have a partitioned table by the column **date** and you want to add new data. In this case, you will have to add the data to the new directory and tell to hive table (specifically to the metastore) that it has a new partition using [ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION COMMAND](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterPartition).

Let's say that you do have not created any table yet. In this case you will have to [create a partitioned table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable) and then [insert the data into this table from queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries). The magic comes up when you set these two flags:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=yes
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
```

These flags allow dynamic partitions (For more details read [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)).

Remember that you will have directories like:

```
/date=YYYYMMDD/fixedname/files
```

So you have to tell to Hive to pick up all the data into subdirectories in a recursive way. You should set the following flag ([here there is a better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756561/how-to-pick-up-all-data-into-hive-from-subdirectories))

```
SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
```

Finally you will able to make queries by date and get all the data in the subdirectories from the date you specified in the query (/date=YYYYMMDD/...).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I created the partitioned table like "create external table(..., ..) partitioned by (date string) location '/basedir'. After that i manually created the folder basedir/date=YYYYMMDD/fixedname/ and copied a file that matches the table structure. However, when i do select * from table i do not see anything inside it.

Comment: Hello @Karan, did you set the flag mapred.input.dir.recursive to true? Also, think about the basedir... is really necessary to have that folder? Because the idea of the partitions is to have the data splitted on the first level. Please tell me how you are defining your table and how is your file.

Comment: Upvoted. The flag is set to true. Having the basedir is a requirement so i cannot change that. The table is defined something like CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName (list of columns) PARTITIONED BY (date String) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LOCATION 'basedir/tableName/'

And then on hdfs, i have basedir/tableName/2015-07-17. All files are inside the date folder. The files have fields separated by '\t'. The directory structure above is different from the initial question i asked because i had to change it.

Comment: Perfect, that's correct. I think I understand what is your problem. Are you defining your directory structure literally like this 'basedir/tableName/2015-07-17'? You should change that for 'basedir/tableName/date=2015-07-17'. Then run the command "MSCK REPAIR TABLE NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE;".  Try that and tell me how this goes.

Comment: So that works but i had to manually say "alter table tableName add partition (date='2015-07-17') location '/basedir/tableName/date=2015-07-17';

So everytime there is a new date directory, i need to execute alter table command? My hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode is still set to strict as i haven't modified it. Is that a per user setting or does it affect all users using the same hive server? I don't want to break other's code.

Comment: If the date=yyyy-mm-dd directories are being added dynamically, i need to execute the alter table command to let hive know about the newly added directory? Is there a way for me to configure hive so that it automatically picks up files from all existing date directories without executing the alter table command for every directory?

Comment: Q: So everytime there is a new date directory, i need to execute alter table command?
A: If you are inserting data manually in the directories, yes. This is because Hive metastore does know that a new partition (new date directory) was added.

Q:  My hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode is still set to strict as i haven't modified it. Is that a per user setting or does it affect all users using the same hive server?

A: This is only per user setting and the default value is strict, so don't worry about it. I recommend you always use it as a strict.

Comment: @Karan, about the last question, yes there is a way. Did you read about MSCK command? (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)). I think using this command you are gonna get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will check that command out. Answer accepted!